# There is any way to make two objects "siblings" without parent? [JAVA]

Tags: java

Ok, maybe I´m asking a total nonsense here, but here is the deal.

I have two java clases A and B that comes from different libraries, that looks somethink like

```
public class A {
method1()
}

public class B {
method1()
method2()
}
```

Later, I want something like

```
if (condition)
temp = new A()
else
temp = new B()
```

so later I´ll be able to use

```
temp.method1()
```

without thinking if its A or B

I guess that if A and B inherits from a parent C, this would be easy, but that´s not the case neither I can change it...

So... is there a elegant way to solve this?

I´m mapping both objects into a third one, but I find it cumbersome. So... any ideas?

Comment: reflection might be your only option. type of `temp` would have to be `Object` though

Comment: create your own interface and implement it in both classes

Comment: Is the reason you can't make a common parent because you can't edit the code for `A` and `B`?

Comment: OP cannot modify class

Comment: If the two classes are from external libraries, it would be necessary to extend A and B with two of your own classes (C & D), and implement interface E on C & D.  Would that work?

Comment: define `Object temp = new A();`. Then you can do `temp = new B();`. You'd need to use `temp instanceof A` and `temp instanceof B` afterwards

Answer (score 4):

I would consider making wrapper interfaces & classes around the base classes.

For example make `interface Method1 { method1(); }` and then make:

```
class AMethod1 implements Method1 { 
  A a; 
  method1() { a.method1(); } 
}
```

with appropriate constructors & what not.

Answer (score 3):

You can try extending both of these class and then you can have full control over them, and then make them implement single interface

Comment: Only issue is if `A` or `B` is final

Comment: then see my answer with wrappers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either try answer provided by @Jigar Joshi or instead of extrending those classes you can write wrappers for them that would implement the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern. This allows you to make incompatible interfaces compatible.

With the Adapter pattern you do not exterd the classes. Instead, you write a new class implementing your interface and forwarding (delegating) the call to the real object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection.

```
public static void invokeMethod1(Object o) throws Exception {       
    o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method1").invoke(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Wrapper {

  public Wrapper(A a)    
  {  this.a = a }

  public Wrapper(B b)    
  {  this.b = b }

  public void method1()
  {
    if(a == null)
      b.method1();
    else
      a.method1();
  }
 }
```

A bit brute force, but it would work.